# How to capture the image fast using gstreamer

Tags: python, python-2.7, gstreamer, raspberry-pi3

I wanted to capture the image by 300milliseconds or less. But i capture the image by 800millisecond by using the codes below. Anybody can help me solve this? Been trying this for quite long but no idea why i cant capture the image by 300millisecond. I using raspberry pi to capture the image.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject #,Gtk
from gi.repository import Gst as gst
class TakePhoto:
  def __init__(self):
    GObject.threads_init()
    gst.init(None)
    self.pipeline = gst.Pipeline()
    self.video_source = gst.ElementFactory.make('v4l2src', 'video_source')
    self.video_source.set_property("num-buffers", 1)
    self.vconvert = gst.ElementFactory.make('videoconvert', 'vconvert')
    self.clock = gst.ElementFactory.make('clockoverlay', 'clock')
    self.timer= gst.ElementFactory.make('timeoverlay','timer')
    self.vrate = gst.ElementFactory.make('videorate', 'vrate')
    self.sconvert = gst.ElementFactory.make('videoconvert', 'sconvert')
    self.png = gst.ElementFactory.make('jpegenc', 'png')
    self.multi_sink = gst.ElementFactory.make('multifilesink', 'multi_sink')

    self.caps = gst.caps_from_string ("video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=800,height=600,framerate=5/1")
    self.timer.set_property('valignment','bottom')
    self.timer.set_property('halignment','right')
    self.clock.set_property('time-format','%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
    self.clock.set_property('valignment','bottom')
    self.caps1 = gst.caps_from_string("video/x-raw,framerate=1/1")
    self.png.set_property('idct-method',1)
    self.multi_sink.set_property('location','/home/pi/frame.jpeg')
    self.filter = gst.ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", "filter")
    self.filter.set_property("caps", self.caps)
    self.filter1 = gst.ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", "filter1")
    self.filter1.set_property("caps", self.caps1)
    self.pipeline.add(self.video_source)
    self.pipeline.add(self.vconvert)
    self.pipeline.add(self.timer)
    self.pipeline.add(self.clock)
    self.pipeline.add(self.filter)
    self.pipeline.add(self.vrate)
    self.pipeline.add(self.filter1)
    self.pipeline.add(self.sconvert)
    self.pipeline.add(self.png)
    self.pipeline.add(self.multi_sink)
    self.video_source.link(self.filter)
    self.filter.link(self.vconvert)
    self.vconvert.link(self.timer)
    self.timer.link(self.clock)
    self.clock.link(self.vrate)
    self.vrate.link(self.filter1)
    self.filter1.link(self.sconvert)
    self.sconvert.link(self.png)
    self.png.link(self.multi_sink)

def take_photo(self): #this is reusable
    bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
    self.pipeline.set_state(gst.State.PLAYING)
    print "Capture started"
    msg = bus.timed_pop_filtered(gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE,gst.MessageType.ERROR | gst.MessageType.EOS)
    #print msg

    self.pipeline.set_state(gst.State.READY)
```

Comment: An RPI is not exactly a high performance platform for CPU performance. The jpeg encoding can take a considerable amount of CPU time here. Try saving your image as raw bitmap image instead and see if it helps your runtime.

Comment: You may have better luck if you leave the program always running and then write the JPEG in response to a user input.  Some of that 800 milliseconds is going to be the act of starting up GStreamer, connecting to v4l2, etc.  You may also see if v4l2src can give you a jpeg directly (it does have caps image/jpeg).

Comment: @mpr do you know how to change my pipeline to dynamic using python?

Comment: @mpr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37963125/how-to-change-my-current-pipeline-to-dynamic-in-python

Comment: @mpr is it possible if i change my pipeline to dynamic then it can capture the image faster?

Answer (score 0):

What I'd suggest trying is to use a pipeline of this form:

> v4l2src ! videoconvert ! clockoverlay ! timeoverlay ! jpegenc !
>   fakesink name=sink

Then in take_photo(), grab the fakesink, access the `last-sample` property.  Extract the data from the sample and render it to the desired file.

I don't know how much time that will give you, but at least you won't have any of the pipeline startup time and the v4l2src element won't have to re-access the camera every time.

If that works, I'd then go back and add a valve into the pipeline:

> v4l2src ! valve name=valve drop=true ! videoconvert ! clockoverlay ! timeoverlay ! jpegenc !
>   fakesink name=sink

..and enable/disable that as needed to reduce the net load on the Pi when the screenshots weren't needed.

There may also be some things that you're trying to do with the framerate that are causing issues.  I think you want to take the video in at the highest framerate possible at the desired resolution, otherwise there may be a natural delay built in, say 200ms if your framerate is 5/1.

Comment: But i need do dynamic pipeline as i will need to do video too. You got any idea how to do it with python because i cant find any source code that can do dynamic pipeline with python.

Comment: If you want to get good help on stackoverflow you're gonna have to work on breaking your questions down.  You didn't even mention playing video in addition to doing the JPEG captures in the original question.  I'd suggest looking into the `tee` element or executing a separate process to take the raw video buffer and convert it to a jpeg.

Comment: But the last-sample property does not exist in 1.0